# Picture in different size with media queries

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap-3, media, image-size

I have the following problem. I want a picture for each device represent in different size. Provide examples I have only once brought Apple devices. Later I would like general media queries. However, the image is always displayed in originial size. Where is my mistake?

Also, I use bootstrap 3.

**Html-Code**

```
<div class="widewrapper main">
      <img src="dev/img/black_linen_v2.png">
</div>
```

**CSS-Code:**

```
@import '../bootstrap-3.0.3/bootstrap';

/* iPhone 4 (landscape) */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) {
.widewrapper.main img {
            margin-top: 75px;
            height:10px;
            width: 100%;
    }
}

/* iPhone 4 (portrait) */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) {
.widewrapper.main img {
            margin-top: 75px;
            height:10px;
            width: 100%;
    }
}

/* iPhone 5 (landscape) */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : landscape) {
.widewrapper.main img {
            margin-top: 75px;
            height:10px;
            width: 100%;
    }
}

/* iPhone 5 (portrait) */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : portrait) {
.widewrapper.main img {
            margin-top: 75px;
            height:10px;
            width: 100%;
    }
}


/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {
.widewrapper.main img {
            margin-top: 75px;
            height:10px;
            width: 100%;
    }
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
.widewrapper.main img {
            margin-top: 75px;
            height:10px;
            width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? Sorry for my bad english. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the same code in each media query?

```
.widewrapper.main img {
        margin-top: 75px;
        height:10px;
        width: 100%;
}
```

Thus your image is the same size....You need to put different values in media queries to see some effect.

Try changing the image width like width: 100px or width: 75% in different media queries..

Also remove the height attribute then.

Comment: That was just a test. But he never change the height. So the picture has nowhere 10px attribute. He shows me only the orginial size.

Comment: Try just using the width attribute with different values and see if it works. (delete the height, img attribute resizes the images height and width based on one attribute, while keeping the image proportions and that might be the reason you didnt see anything since you said height: 10px and width: 100%)

Comment: Ah okay thanks. Now it works :D!
It's that simple. I should try it first, sorry.
I thought if I make it so it shows me on all devices the same height.

But there is a new problem. He takes on the iPhone 4, the attributes of the iphone 5 How can I change this? I have taken different heights attributes.

Comment: your media queries get picked up by the browser in a TOP-DOWN fashion. So for iphone 4 you have: min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px and for iphone 5 :min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) ->>>>Both phones have min device width of 320px, so the last css rule you wrote will be applied for height, width...

Answer (score 2):

You are overwritting the image attribute.So, try putting important next to attribute to give maximum priority.Don't give important to all the attributes...

Eg, 
.widewrapper.main img {margin-top: 75px !important;height:10px;width: 100% !important;}